# Setting 4 tables besides each other with different title for each and Global name for the group

Tags: tables

I trying to organize my tables. I have 4 tables and want to put them beside each other with different title for each and a  name for the whole group. 
I tried with \minipage and subcaption but didn't work.
I want to use these titles for them respectively.

```
Maximum value of $y_{2} $ 
Mean value of $y_{2}$
Median value of $y_{2} $ 
Equilibrium value of $y_{2}$
```

My tables are :

```
\documentclass[14pt, a4paper, twoside]{report} % 'twoside' when printing

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             % UTF-8 input
\usepackage[english]{babel}             % Set language to english
\usepackage{blindtext}                  % Use \Blinddocument or \blindmathpaper
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {/Users/farha/Documents/Master_oppgave/images/} }                    % For graphics
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                   % Fancy headers
\usepackage{hyperref}                   % Internal and external hyperlinks
\usepackage{amsmath}                % Math from AMS
\usepackage{amsfonts}                   % Fonts from AMS
\usepackage{amsthm}                     % Theorems
\usepackage{amssymb}                    % Symbols
\usepackage{enumitem}                   % Enumeration
\usepackage{mathtools}                  % Bonus
\usepackage{color}                      % Colors
\usepackage{booktabs}                   % Professional tables
\usepackage{pdfpages}                   % To include PDFs
\usepackage{parskip}                
\usepackage{multicol}                   % For multiple columns
\usepackage[sharp]{easylist}            % For easy lists
\usepackage{makeidx}                    % For the index
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}   % For algorithms
\usepackage{tikz-cd}                    % For diagrams
\usepackage{listings}                   % To include Python-code
\usepackage{etoolbox}                   % To add symbol at end of examples
\usepackage[expansion=false]{microtype} % Fixes to make typography better
\usepackage[toc, page]{appendix}        % To include appendices
%\usepackage[headings]{fullpage}        % Smaller margins
\usepackage[margin = 3cm, includehead, includefoot]{geometry}
%\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}              % A nice font, alternative to CM
\usepackage{framed}                     % To frame comments
\usepackage{multirow}                   % For multiple rows in tables
\usepackage{afterpage}                  % To insert blank pages
\usepackage{blindtext}                  % To insert some blind text

\usepackage{graphics}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xpatch,amsthm}
\usepackage{fourier, erewhon}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array, caption, floatrow, tabularx, makecell, booktabs}%
\captionsetup{labelfont = sc}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@thm}{\fontseries\mddefault\upshape}{}{}{} % same font as thm-header
\makeatother
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]  
\theoremstyle{plain}
%\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter] % reset theorem numbering for each chapter
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{remark}{Remark}
%\newtheorem{exmp}[thm]{Example} % same for example numbers
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}

\makeatletter
\def\th@plain{%
    \thm@notefont{}% same as heading font
    \itshape % body font
}
\def\th@definition{%
    \thm@notefont{}% same as heading font
    \normalfont % body font
}
\makeatother


\usepackage{array}
% Center the table horizontally
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
% Center the table vertically
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
% Center the table horizontally and vertically
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

%\usepackage[norsk]{babel}

%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
%\theoremstyle{definition}
%\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
% Custom mathematics commands
\newcommand{\DIV}{\div}
\newcommand{\BP}{\left<BP\right>}
\newcommand{\Bzero}{\left<Bzero\right>}
\newcommand{\BQ}{\left<BQ\right>}
\newcommand{\p}{\left<p\right>}
\newcommand{\BF}{\left<BF\right>}
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
\newcommand*\conj[1]{\overline{#1}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\innerprod}[2]{\langle}{\rangle}{#1, #2}
\DeclareMathOperator{\lcm}{lcm}
\DeclareMathOperator{\diag}{diag}
\DeclareMathOperator{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\conv}{\ast}
\DeclareMathOperator{\GL}{\operatorname{GL}}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{xvmatrix}% eXtended vmatrix
{\left.\array{@{}r |@{\,}*\c@MaxMatrixCols c}}
{\endarray\kern-\arraycolsep\right|}

% A command to add a blank page
\newcommand\blankpage{%
    \null
    \newpage}

% Header set up with fancyhdr
\lhead[\nouppercase{\leftmark}]{\thepage} % EVEN, ODD
\rhead[\thepage]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}} % EVEN, ODD
\cfoot[]{}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{normal}{%
    % Header set up with fancyhdr
    \lhead[\nouppercase{\leftmark}]{\thepage} % EVEN, ODD
    \rhead[\thepage]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}} % EVEN, ODD
    \cfoot[]{}}
\fancypagestyle{noheadername}{%
    % Header set up with fancyhdr
    \lhead[]{\thepage} % EVEN, ODD
    \rhead[\thepage]{} % EVEN, ODD
    \cfoot[]{}}

% Declare first page in every chapter as 'fancy' pagestyle
\makeatletter


\renewcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi

    \thispagestyle{fancy}%
    \global\@topnum\z@
    \@afterindentfalse
    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
\toprule
{} &   $S_{1}$ \\
\midrule
$x_{0}$        &  0.999098 \\
$\omega_{11}$  &  0.000131 \\
$\omega_{22}$  &  0.000091 \\
$\phi_{12}$    &  0.000022 \\
$\beta_{2}$    &  0.000015 \\
${y_{1}}_{0}$  & -0.000019 \\
$\epsilon_{1}$ & -0.000075 \\
${y_{2}}_{0}$  & -0.000094 \\
$f_{1}$        & -0.000113 \\
$r$            & -0.000150 \\
$f_{2}$        & -0.000154 \\
$\beta_{1}$    & -0.000157 \\
$\epsilon_{2}$ & -0.000161 \\
$\psi_{12}$    & -0.000218 \\
$k$            & -0.000295 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{lr}
\toprule
{} &   $S_{1}$ \\
\midrule
$f_{2}$        &  0.032545 \\
$f_{1}$        &  0.006636 \\
$\beta_{1}$    &  0.003933 \\
$r$            &  0.000856 \\
$\beta_{2}$    &  0.000193 \\
$\omega_{22}$  &  0.000160 \\
$\psi_{12}$    &  0.000151 \\
$x_{0}$        &  0.000126 \\
$\epsilon_{1}$ &  0.000117 \\
$\omega_{11}$  &  0.000025 \\
${y_{1}}_{0}$  & -0.000004 \\
${y_{2}}_{0}$  & -0.000096 \\
$\phi_{12}$    & -0.000140 \\
$\epsilon_{2}$ & -0.000157 \\
$k$            & -0.000176 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{lr}
\toprule
{} &   $S_{1}$ \\
\midrule
$f_{2}$        &  0.028406 \\
$f_{1}$        &  0.006187 \\
$\beta_{1}$    &  0.003582 \\
$r$            &  0.000620 \\
$\omega_{22}$  &  0.000150 \\
$\epsilon_{1}$ &  0.000113 \\
$\psi_{12}$    &  0.000108 \\
$\beta_{2}$    &  0.000031 \\
$\omega_{11}$  &  0.000024 \\
$x_{0}$        &  0.000011 \\
${y_{1}}_{0}$  & -0.000001 \\
${y_{2}}_{0}$  & -0.000114 \\
$\phi_{12}$    & -0.000135 \\
$\epsilon_{2}$ & -0.000163 \\
$k$            & -0.000168 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{lr}
\toprule
{} &   $S_{1}$ \\
\midrule
$f_{2}$        &  0.007005 \\
$f_{1}$        &  0.001013 \\
$\beta_{1}$    &  0.000588 \\
$r$            &  0.000264 \\
$\psi_{12}$    &  0.000079 \\
$\omega_{11}$  &  0.000073 \\
$\epsilon_{1}$ &  0.000062 \\
$\epsilon_{2}$ &  0.000015 \\
${y_{2}}_{0}$  &  0.000009 \\
$x_{0}$        &  0.000005 \\
$\omega_{22}$  &  0.000003 \\
$k$            & -0.000021 \\
$\beta_{2}$    & -0.000063 \\
$\phi_{12}$    & -0.000086 \\
${y_{1}}_{0}$  & -0.000090 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

\end{document}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried with `subcaption` and it did work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{subtable}[t]{.22\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lr}
\toprule
{} &   $S_{1}$ \\
\midrule
$x_{0}$        &  0.999098 \\
$\omega_{11}$  &  0.000131 \\
$\omega_{22}$  &  0.000091 \\
$\phi_{12}$    &  0.000022 \\
$\beta_{2}$    &  0.000015 \\
${y_{1}}_{0}$  & -0.000019 \\
$\epsilon_{1}$ & -0.000075 \\
${y_{2}}_{0}$  & -0.000094 \\
$f_{1}$        & -0.000113 \\
$r$            & -0.000150 \\
$f_{2}$        & -0.000154 \\
$\beta_{1}$    & -0.000157 \\
$\epsilon_{2}$ & -0.000161 \\
$\psi_{12}$    & -0.000218 \\
$k$            & -0.000295 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Maximum value of $y_{2}$.}
\end{subtable}\hfill
\begin{subtable}[t]{.22\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lr}
\toprule
{} &   $S_{1}$ \\
\midrule
$f_{2}$        &  0.032545 \\
$f_{1}$        &  0.006636 \\
$\beta_{1}$    &  0.003933 \\
$r$            &  0.000856 \\
$\beta_{2}$    &  0.000193 \\
$\omega_{22}$  &  0.000160 \\
$\psi_{12}$    &  0.000151 \\
$x_{0}$        &  0.000126 \\
$\epsilon_{1}$ &  0.000117 \\
$\omega_{11}$  &  0.000025 \\
${y_{1}}_{0}$  & -0.000004 \\
${y_{2}}_{0}$  & -0.000096 \\
$\phi_{12}$    & -0.000140 \\
$\epsilon_{2}$ & -0.000157 \\
$k$            & -0.000176 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Mean value of $y_{2}$.}
\end{subtable}\hfill
\begin{subtable}[t]{.22\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lr}
\toprule
{} &   $S_{1}$ \\
\midrule
$f_{2}$        &  0.028406 \\
$f_{1}$        &  0.006187 \\
$\beta_{1}$    &  0.003582 \\
$r$            &  0.000620 \\
$\omega_{22}$  &  0.000150 \\
$\epsilon_{1}$ &  0.000113 \\
$\psi_{12}$    &  0.000108 \\
$\beta_{2}$    &  0.000031 \\
$\omega_{11}$  &  0.000024 \\
$x_{0}$        &  0.000011 \\
${y_{1}}_{0}$  & -0.000001 \\
${y_{2}}_{0}$  & -0.000114 \\
$\phi_{12}$    & -0.000135 \\
$\epsilon_{2}$ & -0.000163 \\
$k$            & -0.000168 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Median value of $y_{2}$.}
\end{subtable}\hfill
\begin{subtable}[t]{.22\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lr}
\toprule
{} &   $S_{1}$ \\
\midrule
$f_{2}$        &  0.007005 \\
$f_{1}$        &  0.001013 \\
$\beta_{1}$    &  0.000588 \\
$r$            &  0.000264 \\
$\psi_{12}$    &  0.000079 \\
$\omega_{11}$  &  0.000073 \\
$\epsilon_{1}$ &  0.000062 \\
$\epsilon_{2}$ &  0.000015 \\
${y_{2}}_{0}$  &  0.000009 \\
$x_{0}$        &  0.000005 \\
$\omega_{22}$  &  0.000003 \\
$k$            & -0.000021 \\
$\beta_{2}$    & -0.000063 \\
$\phi_{12}$    & -0.000086 \\
${y_{1}}_{0}$  & -0.000090 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Equilibrium value of $y_{2}$.}
\end{subtable}
\caption{Blub.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, one can improve this by typesetting the numerical values in math mode (and perhaps using `siunitx`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{subtable}[t]{.22\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lr}
\toprule
{} &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{$S_{1}$} \\
\midrule
$x_{0}$        & $ 0.999098$\\
$\omega_{11}$  & $ 0.000131$\\
$\omega_{22}$  & $ 0.000091$\\
$\phi_{12}$    & $ 0.000022$\\
$\beta_{2}$    & $ 0.000015$\\
${y_{1}}_{0}$  & $-0.000019$\\
$\epsilon_{1}$ & $-0.000075$\\
${y_{2}}_{0}$  & $-0.000094$\\
$f_{1}$        & $-0.000113$\\
$r$            & $-0.000150$\\
$f_{2}$        & $-0.000154$\\
$\beta_{1}$    & $-0.000157$\\
$\epsilon_{2}$ & $-0.000161$\\
$\psi_{12}$    & $-0.000218$\\
$k$            & $-0.000295$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Maximum value of $y_{2}$.}
\end{subtable}\hfill
\begin{subtable}[t]{.22\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lr}
\toprule
{} &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{$S_{1}$} \\
\midrule
$f_{2}$        & $ 0.032545$\\
$f_{1}$        & $ 0.006636$\\
$\beta_{1}$    & $ 0.003933$\\
$r$            & $ 0.000856$\\
$\beta_{2}$    & $ 0.000193$\\
$\omega_{22}$  & $ 0.000160$\\
$\psi_{12}$    & $ 0.000151$\\
$x_{0}$        & $ 0.000126$\\
$\epsilon_{1}$ & $ 0.000117$\\
$\omega_{11}$  & $ 0.000025$\\
${y_{1}}_{0}$  & $-0.000004$\\
${y_{2}}_{0}$  & $-0.000096$\\
$\phi_{12}$    & $-0.000140$\\
$\epsilon_{2}$ & $-0.000157$\\
$k$            & $-0.000176$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Mean value of $y_{2}$.}
\end{subtable}\hfill
\begin{subtable}[t]{.22\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lr}
\toprule
{} &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{$S_{1}$} \\
\midrule
$f_{2}$        & $ 0.028406$\\
$f_{1}$        & $ 0.006187$\\
$\beta_{1}$    & $ 0.003582$\\
$r$            & $ 0.000620$\\
$\omega_{22}$  & $ 0.000150$\\
$\epsilon_{1}$ & $ 0.000113$\\
$\psi_{12}$    & $ 0.000108$\\
$\beta_{2}$    & $ 0.000031$\\
$\omega_{11}$  & $ 0.000024$\\
$x_{0}$        & $ 0.000011$\\
${y_{1}}_{0}$  & $-0.000001$\\
${y_{2}}_{0}$  & $-0.000114$\\
$\phi_{12}$    & $-0.000135$\\
$\epsilon_{2}$ & $-0.000163$\\
$k$            & $-0.000168$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Median value of $y_{2}$.}
\end{subtable}\hfill
\begin{subtable}[t]{.22\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lr}
\toprule
{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$S_{1}$} \\
\midrule
$f_{2}$        & $ 0.007005$\\
$f_{1}$        & $ 0.001013$\\
$\beta_{1}$    & $ 0.000588$\\
$r$            & $ 0.000264$\\
$\psi_{12}$    & $ 0.000079$\\
$\omega_{11}$  & $ 0.000073$\\
$\epsilon_{1}$ & $ 0.000062$\\
$\epsilon_{2}$ & $ 0.000015$\\
${y_{2}}_{0}$  & $ 0.000009$\\
$x_{0}$        & $ 0.000005$\\
$\omega_{22}$  & $ 0.000003$\\
$k$            & $-0.000021$\\
$\beta_{2}$    & $-0.000063$\\
$\phi_{12}$    & $-0.000086$\\
${y_{1}}_{0}$  & $-0.000090$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Equilibrium value of $y_{2}$.}
\end{subtable}
\caption{Blub.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with captions on the top and automatically inserted `$` (one can also use an `array`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{subtable}[b]{.22\linewidth}
\centering
\caption{Maximum value of $y_{2}$.}
\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$}>{$}r<{$}}
\toprule
{} &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{$S_{1}$} \\
\midrule
x_{0}        &  0.999098\\
\omega_{11}  &  0.000131\\
\omega_{22}  &  0.000091\\
\phi_{12}    &  0.000022\\
\beta_{2}    &  0.000015\\
{y_{1}}_{0}  & -0.000019\\
\epsilon_{1} & -0.000075\\
{y_{2}}_{0}  & -0.000094\\
f_{1}        & -0.000113\\
r            & -0.000150\\
f_{2}        & -0.000154\\
\beta_{1}    & -0.000157\\
\epsilon_{2} & -0.000161\\
\psi_{12}    & -0.000218\\
k            & -0.000295\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}\hfill
\begin{subtable}[b]{.22\linewidth}
\centering
\caption{Mean value of $y_{2}$.}
\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$}>{$}r<{$}}
\toprule
{} &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{$S_{1}$} \\
\midrule
f_{2}        &  0.032545\\
f_{1}        &  0.006636\\
\beta_{1}    &  0.003933\\
r            &  0.000856\\
\beta_{2}    &  0.000193\\
\omega_{22}  &  0.000160\\
\psi_{12}    &  0.000151\\
x_{0}        &  0.000126\\
\epsilon_{1} &  0.000117\\
\omega_{11}  &  0.000025\\
{y_{1}}_{0}  & -0.000004\\
{y_{2}}_{0}  & -0.000096\\
\phi_{12}    & -0.000140\\
\epsilon_{2} & -0.000157\\
k            & -0.000176\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}\hfill
\begin{subtable}[b]{.22\linewidth}
\centering
\caption{Median value of $y_{2}$.}
\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$}>{$}r<{$}}
\toprule
{} &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{$S_{1}$} \\
\midrule
f_{2}        &  0.028406\\
f_{1}        &  0.006187\\
\beta_{1}    &  0.003582\\
r            &  0.000620\\
\omega_{22}  &  0.000150\\
\epsilon_{1} &  0.000113\\
\psi_{12}    &  0.000108\\
\beta_{2}    &  0.000031\\
\omega_{11}  &  0.000024\\
x_{0}        &  0.000011\\
{y_{1}}_{0}  & -0.000001\\
{y_{2}}_{0}  & -0.000114\\
\phi_{12}    & -0.000135\\
\epsilon_{2} & -0.000163\\
k            & -0.000168\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}\hfill
\begin{subtable}[b]{.22\linewidth}
\caption{Equilibrium value of $y_{2}$.}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$}>{$}r<{$}}
\toprule
{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$S_{1}$} \\
\midrule
f_{2}        &  0.007005\\
f_{1}        &  0.001013\\
\beta_{1}    &  0.000588\\
r            &  0.000264\\
\psi_{12}    &  0.000079\\
\omega_{11}  &  0.000073\\
\epsilon_{1} &  0.000062\\
\epsilon_{2} &  0.000015\\
{y_{2}}_{0}  &  0.000009\\
x_{0}        &  0.000005\\
\omega_{22}  &  0.000003\\
k            & -0.000021\\
\beta_{2}    & -0.000063\\
\phi_{12}    & -0.000086\\
{y_{1}}_{0}  & -0.000090\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}
\caption{Blub.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As usual, when there is no complete example, one has to guess certain things like the page geometry. There is no way of telling whether the guess has much to do with your real document, which is why users are strongly encouraged to upload a complete minimal working example.

Comment: How to but titles (except group title) on the top? and is there a way to put the  number in math mode or I have to it manually?

Comment: @F.O I added a version in which the `$`s get inserted automatically, and the subcaptions are at the top.

Comment: @ Schrödinger's cat Very nice. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ Schrödinger's cat I am getting this error for each line.``` Missing $ inserted. $x_{0}$ &```

Comment: @F.O Obviously I do not get this error with any of the above codes. This means most likely that you use them in a modified form. If I had to guess, I'd say you forget to load `\usepackage{array}`, but I can really not tell for sure.

Comment: @ Schrödinger's cat I manged to make it work by using the second version but the tables are out of  \subsubsection and I want it to be under it as I have many tables like this.I have chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection and the table should be under subsubsection

Comment: @F.O Could you please ask a new question on this (which is free of charge), in which you post an as minimal as possible but complete example. I am sure that you will get excellent answers, also because new questions get, unlike older questions, seen by many users.

Comment: @ Schrödinger's cat I will do it

Comment: @ Schrödinger's cat If I want the two last tables under the first two one ,what I should do as i have bigger 4 tables which don't fit beside each other. Is it better to post new question for this as well?